# How do I preselect checkboxes in mat-tree?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I am trying to preselect checkboxes of this mat-tree example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-checklist. For some reason I can't preselect checkboxes at the initalization of the component.

I am trying to combine two rxjs observables with combineLatest. First one contains data nodes for the mat-tree. Second one contains the data nodes which should be preselected. This is my not-working solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-checklist-rj4ryd?file=app/app.component.ts

Mat-tree itself is working with `this.allData$`, but checking selected checkboxes at the initalization of the component with the `this.selectedData$` does not work.

```js
  combineLatest(this.allData$, this.selectedData$)
      .subscribe(val => {
        this.dataSource.data = val[0]
        val[1].map(x => this.nodeSelectionToggle(x))
   }
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code, you are trying to select `GameNode` instance [from `selectedData`] which is not the same instance in `allData`. Notice different `new GameData`. Both are referring to different memory locations.

**You must select the `GameNode` instance from the `allData`.** Try changing your `combineLatest` like this:

```
combineLatest(this.allData$, this.selectedData$)
      .subscribe(val => {
        const data = val[0];
        this.dataSource.data = data;
        this.nodeSelectionToggle(data[1]);
      }
     );
```

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-checklist-re96eq?file=app/app.component.ts

Hope it helps.